# I installed Haiku on my Windows 7 machine. How do I create a boot menu?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, haiku

I just installed [Haiku](http://www.haiku-os.org/) on my Windows 7 laptop, and I don't know how to create a boot menu. I had BeOS running a few years ago, and that came with one built-in. I know my way around computers enough to mess around with partitions and whatnot, but my recent Googling has made me believe that boot menu stuff is over my head. Is there a simple solution, or can somebody walk me through the process so I don't have to boot from the CD?

Comment: An "Haiku" type of answer to this question would reach unknown levels of awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix it with [Super Grub disk Live CD](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2677-super-grub-disk-live-cd).

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread over on the [**Haiku forums**](http://www.haiku-os.org/community/forum/dual_booting_haiku_and_windows_7#comment-12304) about this.

They suggest using the **bootman** tool to create the boot menu, simply type bootman into the Console and follow the instructions.

Quoted straight from the forum, posted by Denise Purple:

> Actually, bootman is very easy to set
>   up and use. I recently tried it for
>   the first time, since GRUB2 kept
>   failing to boot Haiku for some reason.
>   As mentioned above, you can type the
>   "bootman" command in the terminal. A
>   rather straight-forward wizard will
>   show up. Windows 7 usually creates one
>   system partition and one 100MB boot
>   partition. Don't mind the system
>   partition, just use the 100MB one. As
>   well, make sure your Haiku partition
>   is also checked. ;) If you want to use
>   Linux you may have issues though, but
>   it may be solveable, I'm not sure. If
>   you're not interested in that though,
>   I see no problem with using bootman.

Comment: `bootman` is now `BootManager` from the Terminal if anyone goes to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could get a copy of a linux distribution and begin the installation but only install the bootloader, [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB).

You'd have to know which partitions you need for what OS though. Make sure you thoroughly read the docs for whatever you're downloading so that you can stop the install process before installing the OS.

Let us know if you want more details with a particular distribution.